# Formatear fecha en input

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando formatear la fecha que muestro en el siguiente div.

```
 <input style="width:100%;" type="text" value="{{ FECHA_INGRESO }}" />
```

El problema que tengo es que la fecha me aparece 22/2/2023 y deberia ser 2023/02/22. Originalmente la fecha viene así '2023-02-22T00:00:00'

La data la obtienen de la siguiente forma y le agregue un formateo a la fecha:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "GestionPersonal/obtenerEmpleado",
        data: {
            IdEmpleado: id
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        let row = JSON.parse(data);
        row.FECHA_INGRESO = new Date(Date.parse(row.FECHA_INGRESO )).toLocaleDateString({ format: "YYYY-MM-dd" });
        callbackDatos(row);
    });
```

Por favor me podrían ayudar diciéndome como debo formatear la fecha, gracias.

Comment: Y la variable que tienes en el value del input?

Comment: Usas algún lenguaje de backend que te retorna la fecha? Porque de ser así, la puedes formatear desde el backend. Con `php` por ejemplo, se puede dar el formato deseado combinando las funciones `date` y `strtotime` así: `<?=date("Y/m/d", strtotime("2023-02-22T00:00:00"));?>` y las salida queda tal como la buscas **2023/02/22**

Answer (score 0):

en javascript podrias aplicar esto.

```js
// Crear una instancia de Date con la fecha original
let fechaOriginal = '2023-02-22T00:00:00';
console.log(fechaOriginal);
let fecha = new Date(fechaOriginal);
console.log(fecha);

// Extraer los componentes de la fecha
let dia = fecha.getDate();
let mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1; // Agregar 1 porque los meses comienzan en 0
let anio = fecha.getFullYear();

// Crear la fecha en el formato deseado (dd/mm/aaaa)
let fechaFormateada = anio + '/' + mes + '/' + dia;

// Mostrar la fecha formateada en la consola
console.log(fechaFormateada); // Output: "22/02/2023"
```

Comment: No entiendo como esto soluciona el problema de OP....

Comment: le entregaste el formato exactamente como el ya lo tenía